# Establecer que test lanzar en comandos maven consola

Tags: java, maven, junit

Tengo una serie de test los cuales testean diversas situaciones que puede dar la lógica de negocio.

```
public class IntegrationTest {

public IntegrationTest() {
    super();
}

@Test
public void successfulFlow() throws Exception {
    SuccessfulFlowTest.getInstance().run();
}

@Test
public void failureFlow() throws Exception {
    CreationStateFailureTest.getInstance().run();
}

@Test
public void successfulFlowWithPartner() throws Exception {
    SuccessfulFlowWithPartnerTest.getInstance().run();
}

@Test
public void handlerTest() throws Exception {
    HandlerTest.getInstance().run();
}
}
```

A la hora de lanzar los test con mvn test -e hay alguna forma de ejecutar el test que le pase como parametro. Me refiero, algo similar a:

> mvn test -e 'handlerTest'

O por lo contrario, ¿debería de segmentar los test que quiera lanzar en distintas clases para así seleccionar clases en vez de métodos? De ser esa una opción como debería de ejecutarlo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lanzarlo siguiendo el patrón `mvn -Dtest=Clase#test test`
Por ejemplo:

```
mvn -Dtest=IntegrationTest#handlerTest test
```

También puedes usar una máscara en el nombre de método:

```
mvn -Dtest=IntegrationTest#*Flow test
```

Así se lanzarían `successfulFlow` y `failureFlow`

Comment: A que bueno, y si mi librería de testing es JUnit. Lo ejecutara sin ningún inconveniente? Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Si es una versión 4.x, sí